# GLKit / OpenGL-ES 2.0 - 2D Object World Space and 2D Camera

Tags: ios, opengl-es, camera, 2d, glkit

I am new to OpenGL-es 2.0 and GLKit,
and would like to ask a question.
I tried to find a good example on 2D camera but couldn't find any,
so I hope that you guys can help me :D

--

1)
Firstly, I have an object, and I store its position in GLKVector2.
I would like to know how to draw it in the world space.

2)
I have a "2D Camera" class, storing as a CGRect with its world position and size.
Its size may change depending on the "zoom" I want.
Is there any way to easily draw the objects from world space into this 2D Camera?
Is any optimization required too? such as not drawing objects outside this 2D Camera,
and clipping objects that have some parts outside of 2D Camera.

3)
If the objects are drawn into this 2D camera, how do I apply effects like clip/scale/etc so that it fits on the device screen, and draw it on the screen?

--

I have seen many things about model, view, and projection matrix, but I don't get them. I have only done XNA/Android bitmap drawing calls, which is drawing them onto a Bitmap, and resizing the Bitmap onto the screen.